# wxGlade GUI behavioural problems

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxglade

I have designed a GUI with wxGlade in python and the design **within** the program looks fine.

[image]

But once i had generated the code and ran it in idle, it looks much different.

[image]

I would like to know why this has happened, what went wrong and what i can do to fix this problem.

I am using Python 2.7(32bit) and Windows 7 with the latest wxpython and wxglade installation.

The wxglade file is here: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/cH4kAoUk6S/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stretch the borders of your app on run, the elements are there.
For some reason, the elements are not being drawn on load, but instead on event change.

For seeing the results as it should, un-check the size option, save and generate code :)

[image: size]

Comment: Do you know how to implement this in wxglade?

Comment: If i am disabling the size option, how do i set the size of the window in the end?

Comment: @vjgaero: you can manually add the size in the code. I recommend leaving it off, it will dynamically set the size :) On an entirely different note, right now I am the servant of SATAN (666 rep XD)